# Improve call quality - Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, voice, twilio-api

I'm currently using twilio trial account. Is there any functions available in twilio to improve the call quality or any paid services available to receive overall higher call quality by paying more.

When I researched I found only docs related to [call feedback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call-feedback).

If anyone has idea on this, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are having problems with call quality I'd recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to see how they can help.